# Google receipt format for purchases made using Google play on Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am trying to implement in app purchase in my application. I am trying to use test ids for checking the flow.

when I pass `android.test.purchased` as item SKU to purchase, I get following response as purchase

```
{"packageName":"com.sample.goo","orderId":"transactionId.android.test.purchased","productId":"android.test.purchased","developerPayload":"PRODUCT_SKU_AND_USER_ID_AND_DATE","purchaseTime":0,"purchaseState":0,"purchaseToken":"inapp:com.sample.goo:android.test.purchased"}
```

But at many places I found that the data returned by Google is in the following format

```
{
    "nonce": 1165723044405495300,
    "orders": [
        {
            "notificationId": "android.test.purchased",
            "orderId": "transactionId.android.test.purchased",
            "packageName": "com.company.appname",
            "productId": "android.test.purchased",
            "purchaseTime": 1335874740360,
            "purchaseState": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I am not sure why I am not getting the response in the above format.

Can anybody tell me what can be wrong here?

Comment: Which version of in-App billing you are using?

Comment: I am using IAB API V3

Comment: refer http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html for detailed response for every API call.

Comment: Here is there is no mention of Nonce

Comment: Yes you are right it is mentioned in version-2 and security section not in version-3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using V3 API of google in app billing, the response you receive is correct. 
The visible differences in the responses of v3 and v2 are

1. v3 doesn't have a nonce sent/received.
2. v3 has the new parameter, 'developer payload' that is used to uniquely identify a purchase in addition to purchaseID.